# extract stylesheet visual studio

Tags: css, visual-studio

I've written some css information on elements in my html document. I was wondering, is there any "extract Stylesheet" tool in visual studio, to enalbe me to automatically extract the styles out to an external css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Visual Studio add-in should do what you want: [Aggiorno](http://www.aggiorno.com/what-is-aggiorno-extract-merge-inline-style.aspx)

However in-line styles - even in a prototyping phase - are considered bad practice. If you really don't want to wire up .css files, it's better to have a single `<style/>` block in the `<head/>` that contains all of your classes. This way it can be easily moved to a .css once you're ready.

Comment: There's also http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/ but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such tool in Visual Studio but you could use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/css) to inspect CSS rules applied to a web page.